# How to pass List as argument to dataclass? TypeError: __init__() missing required positional arguments

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I tried this

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
import pandas as pd

@dataclass
class First:
    code_event: str
    code_event_system: str
    company_id: int
    date_event: str
    date_event_real: str
    ecode_class: str
......

d = pd.read_json('my.json', lines=True)
a = d.values.tolist()
```

Output of a

```
[['S1933190', 'STATIC', 3, '2020-05-26 16:30:00.000', '2020-05-26 16:30:00.000', 525065, 86393, '',......]]
```

At this moment, my idea is to put list as an argument.

```
p = First(a)
```

I got TypeError

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 30 required positional arguments: 'code_event_system', 'company_id',
```

From terminal

```
>>> len(a)
1
>>> len(a[0])
30
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can instanciate a class with a list of arguments by doing this: `First(*a)`

The [asterisk is simply unpacking](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/) the list `a` into the arguments of the class constructor `First`.

Comment: Not is not matrix, list ,len(a)=1

Comment: @MikiBelavista Is it of shape (1, 31) then?

Comment: List does not have shape attribute.

Comment: Ok, I'll write the question in another way then, what is `len(a[0])`?

Comment: Take a look now.

Comment: Works now fine,I made typo.